# Forward emails with attachments to all recipients

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I receive emails containing Excel reports as an attachment. They are all from the same sender but have different recipients on each email.

An example:

Email #1

> From: John@gmail.com To: me@gmail.com;mike@gmail.com
>
> +1 attachment Excel file

Email #2

> From: John@gmail.com To: me@gmail.com;jessica@gmail.com
>
> +1 attachment Excel file

I need to forward those emails to the recipients again WITH the attachment file.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? By definition, all recipients would already have gotten the same email with the same attachment, no? i

Answer (score -1):

You could create a [macro rule](https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/rules/outlooks-rules-and-alerts-run-a-script/), when you receive an email from specific sender run a script.
About automatically save attachment, please refer to this code:

```
 Sub Save_Attachment(olItem As Outlook.MailItem)
        Dim olAttch As Outlook.attachment
        Dim sPath As String
        Dim acount
        Dim objMsg As MailItem
        Dim recips As Outlook.Recipients
        Dim recip As Outlook.Recipient

    For Each olAttch In olItem.Attachments
           If olAttch.UnRead = True Then
                If olAttch.SenderEmailAddress = "v-shuail@microsoft.com" Then
                    Set acount = olAttch.Attachments.Count
                    If acount > 0 Then
                        Set objMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
                        Set recips = olAttch.Recipients


                        With objMsg
                          .Subject = "This is the subject"
                          .Attachments.Add ("path-to-file.docx")
                           For Each recip In recips
                            .Recipients.Add (recip)
                           Next
                          .Send
                        End With
                        Set objMsg = Nothing
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next

        Set olAttch = Nothing

End Sub
```